# Grok pattern for log with pipeline seperator

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration

I'm trying to figure out the log pattern for the log pattern below.

```
01/02AVDC190001|00001|4483850000152971|DATAPREP|PREPERATION/ENRICHEMENT                 |020190201|20:51:52|SCHED
```

What I've tried so far is :

```
input {
    file {
        path => "C:/Elasitcity/Logbase/July10_Logs_SDC/*.*"
        start_position => "beginning"
        sincedb_path => "NUL"


        }
      }
filter {
    mutate {
            gsub => ["message","\|"," "]
    }

    grok {
            match => ["message","%{NUMBER:LOGID} %{NUMBER:LOGPHASE} %{NUMBER:LOGID} %{WORD:LOGEVENT} %{WORD:LOGACTIVITY} %{DATE_US: DATE} %{TIME:LOGTIME}"]
    }
}



            }
output  {
    elasticsearch {

                    hosts => "localhost"
                    index => "grokcsv"
                    document_type => "gxs"

                  }
            stdout {}
}
```

I'm also wondering if its possible to combine the data and time since its seperated by a pipeline character. But that's not the primary question,.

Comment: The grok filter is overkill for something like this, use the [dissect filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-csv.html) or the [csv filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-csv.html).

Comment: @baudsp both of your links go to the CSV filter. Here's the correct link for the dissect filter: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-dissect.html

Comment: @mihomir Thank you. It was a copy-paste mistake.